# RE: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file

Tags: android

I'm working on a GPS based application for finding user's current location and for that the AvD that i'm using is Google Apis-API level 19 but on launching the avd i'm getting this error all the time. I have gone through the previous solution to the same problem but could not find it helpful.I tried doing all the things:

1)Installed ARM EABI v7a System Image

2)restarted eclipse after installation

3)have google play services installed

Still getting the same error all the time: "emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!"

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and it ended up being the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT setting.  this needs to point the the [adt dir]\sdk.  mine was set to sdk\tools and hence failed.